# How to convert a cell with a duration (datetime difference) to number in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I have four fields in Numbers on macOS:

1. *F1*: `datetime`
2. *F2*: `datetime`
3. *F3*: `duration`
4. *F4*: `number`

The `dateime`-fieds contain only a time, like:

```
10:00    11:00
11:00    12:30
13:00    13:15
```

The `duration`-field is calculated by this formular:

```
F2 - F1
```

And shows something like:

```
1h
1h 30m
15m
```

This works fine.

---

Now I want to calculate *F4* which is a number representation of the `duration`-field *F3*. For the examples above it should result in:

```
1
1.5
0.25
```

Unfortuanteley I can't find a way to achieve this. *How can this be solved?*

---

What I've tried so far:

- changing the fomatting to `number` didn't work as it will always reset to `duration`
- setting the field *F3* to `seconds`-only and then calculating `F3 / 3600`, but the result will always be a new `duration`

Comment: What have you tried that fails?  A formula, or calculation? Just setting the cell format? A combination? Cheers

Comment: @bjbk Good point - I've updated the question. The problem seems that every formular applied to *F3* will result in a new `duration`-value and never in a `number`.

Comment: Great! I’ll work on it too and see what we can come up with.

Comment: Did you try googling first? I ask because searching e.g. _convert hours and minutes to decimal in numbers_ gave me the DUR2HOURS() formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `DUR2HOURS()` formula.

`DUR2HOURS(F3)`

Pass the duration from F3 to the formula.

[image: Duration to hours example]

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. Didn't know a function like this exists. Thank you very much.